# Повторение в inline режиме | pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Мне необходимо создать бота на telebot использующий inline режим (https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline). Допустим, задача - изменить сообщение на случайное число от 1 до 100.

```
@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) >= 0)
def query_text(inline_query):
    randomnum = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(str(1), 'Рандом число в диапазоне 1-100', types.InputTextMessageContent(str(random.randint(1, 100))))
    bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, [randomnum])
```

В первый раз выводится случайное число, но если повторить это действие, число повторяется, оно одно и то же. Что нужно сделать, чтобы число каждый раз было случайным?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел сам. Дело в КЭШИРОВАНИИ. Оно позволяет меньше нагружать ресурсы устройства, на котором запущен бот, но оно повторяет все сообщения. Если сообщения нужны каждый раз разные, то кэширование просто не нужно.

Отключить кэширование невозможно, но возможно изменить время которое будет длиться кэширование. Можно просто изменить время на 0, т.е. своеобразная замена отсутствующему отключению кэшированию. Поэтому прописываем `, cache_time=0` на конец -

```
bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, [randomnum], cache_time=0)
```